# Трансляция видео с машины

Tags: qt, opencv, ethernet, rtsp, видеонаблюдение

Моя задача - отображать изображения с 4ех камер внутри пользовательского приложения. Камеры соеденены с устройством по локальной сети.
В данный момент камеры подключены к цифровому видеорегистратору Giraffe GF-DV0494 v4, пользовательское приложение написано на Qt5, внутри приложения работает 4 потока (многопоточное программирование), каждый из которых читает кадр из канала DVR (чтение происходит из потоков RTPS с использованием OpenCV).
Требуемое качество для каждого канала - 720p, количество кадров - 25.
Я пробовал много попыток в своем коде, но, к сожалению, время получения 4 кадров, их изменение размеров под экран и отображение превышает временной интервал между кадрами видео (секунда / 25). Из-за этого наблюдается сильная просадка FPS.
Подводя итог, могу сказать: 4 аналоговых камеры, видеорегистратор и устройство с моим приложением находятся в одной локальной сети. Необходимо иметь возможность получать изображение со всех четырех камер одновременно внутри моего приложения без просадки FPS и с минимальной задержкой. Задача может быть осложнена тем, что слабый ПК (неттоп, малина) может выступать в качестве устройства.
Я хотел бы услышать совет. Может стоит сменить видеорегистратор? Что вы можете посоветовать? Или другой подход к коду?

Спасибо за ваш совет заранее!

Comment: Какова пропускная способность сети? Мощность проца? Есть ли видеокарта? Объем оперативной памяти? каждые 40мс вы бросаете по сети 720p - объем данных одного кадра от одной камеры, а их четыре. Вот и считайте, думайте

Comment: Разумеется, я представляю всё это. Вопрос в том, как решить эту задачу. В голову приходило лишь то, что как мы здоро сразу было ьы получать по тому rtsp кадр, который уже будет состоять из соединенных фреймов всех каналов. Может, есть видеорегистратор который может это предложить? Или же возможность запрограммировать такой регистратор самому.